# Adding common.sass file to each file

Tags: sass, webpack

I'm using webpack. I have lots of sass files. Each file imports "common.sass" file. I do not want to write @import "common.sass" in each file. How can I avoid of writing it in each file?
Maybe there is opportunity to add somehow string @import "common.sass" in each file?

Comment: Atlast, there will be only one css file right? if it is so, include a wrapper sass file, where import all necessary sass files instead of importing in each file.

Comment: No, there will be one css for each sass file.

Comment: then instead of using `@import common.sass` use `link` tag in html.

Comment: No, in common.sass there are variables which are used in each sass files.

Comment: then definitely you need to import in each sass file. or else render it automatically using task runners like gulp or grunt.  Check [gulp-nunjucks-render](https://github.com/carlosl/gulp-nunjucks-render)

Comment: I think gulp-nunjucks-render is not necessary in this case. You just need to prepend that import line in all files in the pipe while converting sass to css using gulp or grunt.

Comment: yes, but I use webpack. In gulp I know how to make it, but I do not know how to make it in webpack.

Comment: Why are you adding the import to every file?

Comment: because in this common.sass file there are common variables for each sass file

Comment: AFAIK, you can't do that with webpack. webpack is just dependency loader. you need to use gulp or any other task runner here.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but there are lots of loaders and plugins for webpack and them can do the same things what gulp does, so maybe there is one which makes what I need

Comment: I tried to find concat loader(in gult it is concat plugin), but did not  find such loader...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't avoid the import, because each sass partial is being processed in isolation by your loaders. But, you can avoid having to add that line to each file. [Baggage-loader](https://github.com/deepsweet/baggage-loader/) is a loader that lets you specify other modules that should automatically be included when loading a module. It's pretty simple and flexible, and easy enough to fork and modify if you need to.